# Wrap Text on Image PHP

Tags: php

I hope someone can help me, i need to position my TEXT/STRING to the added border at the bottom part of the image and wrap it or format it.

Here is my code:

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

//$add=$img_link;
$add="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg";

//$string = $verse_ref;
$string = "There are glimpses of heaven to us in every act, or thought, or word, that raises us above ourselves.";
$fontSize = 20;

$border=10; // Change the value to adjust width
$im=ImageCreateFromJpeg($add);

$width=ImageSx($im);
$height=ImageSy($im);

$img_adj_width=$width+(2*$border);
$img_adj_height=$height+(15*$border);

$newimage=imagecreatetruecolor($img_adj_width,$img_adj_height);

$border_color = imagecolorallocate($newimage, 0, 0, 0);

imagefilledrectangle($newimage,0,0,$img_adj_width,$img_adj_height,$border_color);

imageCopyResized($newimage,$im,$border,$border,0,0,$width,$height,$width,$height);


$font_width = ImageFontWidth($font);
$font_height = ImageFontHeight($font);

$text_width = $font_width * strlen($string);
$position_center = ceil(($width - $text_width) / 2);

$text_height = $font_height;
$position_middle = ceil(($height - $text_height) / 2);

$color = imagecolorallocate($newimage, 255, 255, 255);

imagestring($newimage, $fontSize, $position_center, $position_middle, $string, $color);
ImageJpeg($newimage);
```

I get this output on my current code:
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have already drawn a black `10x10x10x140px` border. In the next steps you will have to implement an algorithm similar to the following (pseudo-code):

```
// Calculate the maximum number of characters per line
max_line_chars := floor(width / character_width)

// Calculate the maximum number of lines that will fit the bottom area
max_lines := floor(bottom_black_area_height / character_height)

// Build an array of wrapped lines
lines = get_array_of_word_wrapped_lines(string, max_line_chars)

// Shrink `lines` to the size of maximum number of lines, if necessary
if length_of lines > max_lines then
  lines := shrink(lines, max_lines)
  height_offset := 0
else
  height_offset := floor(((max_lines - length_of lines)) * character_height) / 2)
endif

for line in lines
  line_width := character_width * length_of line

  x := floor((image_width_with_borders - line_width) / 2)
  y := floor(height_of_image + 2 * border_width + height_offset)

  draw_line(x, y, line)

  height_offset := height_offset + character_height
endfor
```

### Example

```
$add = 'test.jpg';
$string = 'My people will live in peaceful dwelling places, in secure homes, in undisturbed places of rest. Isaiah 32:17-18';
$string_len = strlen($string);
$split_words = false;

$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($add);
$width  = imagesx($im);
$height = imagesy($im);

$border         = 10;
$width_delta    = 2 * $border;
$height_delta   = 15 * $border;
$img_adj_width  = $width + $width_delta;
$img_adj_height = $height + $height_delta;

$newimage = imagecreatetruecolor($img_adj_width, $img_adj_height);
$border_color = imagecolorallocate($newimage, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($newimage, 0, 0,
  $img_adj_width, $img_adj_height, $border_color);
imagecopyresized($newimage, $im, $border, $border, 0, 0,
  $width, $height, $width, $height);

$color = imagecolorallocate($newimage, 255, 255, 255);

$font = 4;
$font_width  = imagefontwidth($font);
$font_height = imagefontheight($font);

$max_line_chars = floor($width / $font_width);
$max_lines      = floor(($height_delta - 2 * $border) / $font_height);

$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, wordwrap($string, $max_line_chars, PHP_EOL, false));
if (count($lines) > $max_lines) {
  $lines = array_slice($lines, 0, $max_lines);
  $height_offset = 0;
} else {
  $height_offset = floor((($max_lines - count($lines)) * $font_height) / 2);
}

foreach ($lines as $line) {
  $line_width = $font_width * strlen($line);

  $x = floor(($img_adj_width - $line_width) / 2);
  $y = floor($height + $border * 2 + $height_offset);

  imagestring($newimage, $font, $x, $y, $line, $color);

  $height_offset += $font_height;
}

imagejpeg($newimage);
```

Note, the `wordwrap` function as well as the standard string functions such as `substr` do not support Unicode! For Unicode, you will need to implement your own version of `wordwrap`, and use the [multi-byte string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mbstring.php) instead.

*Sample output*

[image: Sample output]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your given code. But i get this output http://prntscr.com/d0bl6v

Here is the complete string:
“My people will live in peaceful dwelling places, in secure homes, in undisturbed places of rest.” Isaiah 32:17-18

Comment: I thank you for your effort. My original plan is to wrap all text inside the BLACK BORDER at the bottom part. I hope you can help me to do that. Thanks!

Comment: It works! Thanks! One more thing is imagestring() allow changing font file? And how can i make it to auto change font size depends of the lengt of the string?

Comment: @user1578707, you can load custom font with [imageloadfont](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imageloadfont.php) and pass its ID to `imagestring`. If you think the answer fixed your problem, then you should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `$position_middle`-line to `$position_middle = ceil(($height + ($text_height * 4.5)));` and see if that solves the problem.